# Highcharts heatmap logarithmic colorAxis fails when 0

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to implement a heatmap in highcharts with a logarithmic colorAxis, however, I keep getting highcharts error [#10](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/10) (can't plot zero or subzero values on a logarithmic axis).

As I'm trying to apply the logarithmic property to the color axis and not the actual axis themselves, I believe my problem is caused by some of my bins having a frequency of zero (A heatmap colors by the frequency in each bin).

How can I get around this? Can I create a default function so that when a frequency is zero it assigns that bin a default color? I can't find any solutions in the docs.

Currently, my colorAxis object looks like this

```
colorAxis: {
  type: 'logarithmic',
  minColor: '#EEEEFF',
  maxColor: '#000022',
  stops: [
    [0, '#EFEFFF'],
    [0.67, '#4444FF'],
    [1, '#000022']
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to iterate through my data and change all the zeros to an extremely small number then set a `min` property on the `colorAxis` so the extremely small numbers would not interfere with the color scheme. This is obviously not the best solution because if the third dimension was measuring something other than frequency and this other thing could be a fraction less than 1 then the extremely small value could overlay with actual data and throw off the color scheme. Hopefully someone comes along and provides a better solution, but for now this is all the insight I have to give.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithm doesn't have any value in 0 so your solution seems pretty neat. You need to apply some offset to the values that equal 0 - there's no other way.

If you want to be more consistent you can apply the offset to all the values. Then apply `formatters`(tooltip, data labels, color axis' labels) so that the user sees the value without the offset.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/jdf5wrdL/